# A point is moving along the curve $y = x^2$ with unit speed. What is the magnitude of its acceleration at the point $(1/2, 1/4)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics

A point is moving along the curve $y = x^2$ with unit speed. What is the magnitude of its acceleration at the point $(1/2, 1/4)$?

My approach : I use the parametric equation $s(t) = (ct, c^2t^2)$, then $v(t) = s'(t) = (c, 2c^2t)$ and $a(t) = v'(t) = (0, 2c^2)$. Now the point $(1/2, 1/4)$ is reached at time $t = \frac{1}{2c}$, so $v(\frac{1}{2c}) = (c, c)$. Now the unit speed condition gives us $\sqrt{c^2 + c^2} = 1 \implies c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So the magnitude of acceleration is $2c^2 = 1$.

But the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Can someone help me what is wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong is that using the parametric coordinates

$$s(t)=(ct,c^2t^2)$$

the point is not moving with unit speed. This can be easily seen by computing the norm  of the speed, which is not constant. You need to normalize the speed **for all $t$**. Then find the time at which  the point $(1/4,1/2)$ is reached. And finally compute the acceleration at this point.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you a lot for pointing that out. Also, can you please help me how the parametric equation should look so that the speed is unit for all $t$.

Comment: To get the right parametric equation, you have to divide the speed you currently have by its norm.

Comment: Don't think it's easy compute. Assuming $c=1$ the normalized velocity vector becomes $\frac {(1,2t)} {\sqrt {1 + 4t^2}}.$ I have to find the displacement vector now. So the integrating factors should be such that the displacement along the $y$-axis is the square of the displacement along the $x$-axis. Then we have to determine the time $t_0$ when the displacement vector is at the given point. Differentiating the displacement vector twice and evaluate it at $t_0$ would give the acceleration vector and finally we need to find it's magnitude or norm. It's not that easy as you are anticipating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cartesian coordinates for this.
You have $$y=x^2\implies \dot{y}=2x\dot{x}$$
Therefore at $x=\frac12$, $\dot{y}=\dot{x}$

For constant speed we have $${\dot{x}}^2+{\dot{y}}^2=1$$
Hence at $x=\frac12$, $\dot{y}=\dot{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Differentiating with respect to time the curve again, we have $$\ddot{y}=2{\dot{x}}^2+2x\ddot{x}$$

Therefore at $x=\frac12$, we have $$\ddot{y}=1+\ddot{x}$$

Finally, differentiating the constant speed condition gives $$2\dot{x}\ddot{x}+2\dot{y}\ddot{y}=0\implies \ddot{x}=-\ddot{y}$$

So $\ddot{y}=\frac12$ and $\ddot{x}=-\frac12$ and hence the result.